# Prevent testing Head with ReplaceAll

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, replacement, string-manipulation

I have a list of strings `list`. I am trying to get rid of some elements that match string pattern `patt`:

```
list /. x_ /; StringMatchQ[x, patt] -> Nothing
```

I get the result I want but I also get an error:

```
StringMatchQ::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringMatchQ[List, patt].
```

This happens because `ReplaceAll` also evaluates the condition on the Head of `list`. How can I get the result I want but prevent the error?

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [(7688)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7688/121)  Also related: [(17497)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17497/121)

Comment: amrods, thanks for the Accept.  Do you feel that your question is a duplicate of 7688 linked above?  If so we should mark it as such.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: You could use `Quiet` also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMHO the simplest solution is to restrict the pattern on the left side of [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html), i.e. change `x_` to `x_String`:

```
patt = ___ ~~ "a" ~~ ___;

{"good", "bad"} /. x_String /; StringMatchQ[x, patt] -> Sequence[]

(*  {"good"}  *)
```

You can instead use [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html) as indicated in other answers, however:

- the optimal [*levelspec*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29750/121) to target atomic elements like Strings is `{-1}`
- The default [`Heads`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Heads.html) value `False` is what prevents `List` from being pattern matched.

Please understand that `Replace` does not work the same as `ReplaceAll`, regardless of *levelspec*, because it uses a different traversal order. See:

- [How to perform a depth-first preorder traversal of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9233/121)
- [How to remove redundant {} from a nested list of lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20180/how-to-remove-redundant-from-a-nested-list-of-lists/20181#20181)
- [ReplaceRepeated seemingly omits some rules](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38668/121)
- [Using ReplaceAll to replace a head](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56010/121)

Answer (score 6):

Use `Replace` instead of `ReplaceAll`.

```
ReplaceAll[{"x", "y", "z"}, x_ /; StringMatchQ[x, "x"] -> Nothing]
```

> > StringMatchQ::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringMatchQ[List,x].

```
(* {"y", "z"} *)
```

as in the question.  In contrast,

```
Replace[{"x", "y", "z"}, x_ /; StringMatchQ[x, "x"] -> Nothing, {1}]
```

yields the same answer but without the error message.

**Correction**

For nested `List`s, it appears necessary to restrict `patt` to be a `String`, as noted by [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard).

```
Replace[{"x", "y", "z", {"a", "x", {"b", "x"}}}, 
    x_String /; StringMatchQ[x, "x"] -> Nothing, {1, Infinity}]

(* {"y", "z", {"a", {"b"}}} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

**Solution**

You could use `Replace` (`ReplaceAll` is effectively the same as using `All` or `{0, Infinity}` as levelspec in `Replace`).

**Example**

```
list = {"a", "b", "c"};
patt = "a";
Replace[list, x_ /; StringMatchQ[x, patt] -> Nothing, {1, Infinity}]

(* {"b", "c"} *)
```

**Alternative Solution**

In your case, since you are replacing something with `Nothing`, you could simply use `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[list, patt, All]

(* {"b", "c"} *)
```

Comment: Change the levelspec as needed. (If your list is level 1, then `{1}` would be enough)

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {"x", "y", "z", "x"};
```

Showing some of the newer functions

`ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[_ :> Nothing, Position[list, "x"]] @ list
```

{"y", "z"}

`SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
First @ SequenceSplit[list, {"x"}]
```

{"y", "z"}

`SequenceReplace` (new in 11.3)

```
SequenceReplace[list, {"x"} :> Nothing]
```

{"y", "z"}

`DeleteElements` (new in 13.1)

```
DeleteElements[list, {"x"}]
```

{"y", "z"}

*The above functions are rather slow when applied to large lists.*

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `StringCases` and `Except`:

```
list = {"x", "y", "z", "x"};

Catenate@StringCases[list, {Except["x"]}]

(*{"y", "z"}*)
```